# How to pass a variable into the onclick method in a html element

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, tabulator

Im currently using the [tabulator library](http://tabulator.info) to create tables based on json data.
I am trying to use a custom cell formatter to add a button into a cell.

Here is my method:

```
var graphButton = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
   var button = '<button   onclick="customMethod(cell.getRow().getData())">myLabel</button>';
   return button;
};
```

I then pass `graphButton` into the table's definition.

The button is displayed correctly. However, when I click the button, I get an error stating: `can't find variable: cell`.

How do I correctly pass the cell variable into `customMethod`?

Comment: Have you tried using the [cellClick library](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/callbacks#cell) built in with library? Example below, found in the examples tab.
`cellClick:function(e, cell){alert("Printing row data for: " + cell.getRow().getData().name)}`

Comment: Yes however this is not the functionality I want. I would like a button within the cell that has to be clicked, rather than the cell itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this way not sure but as per standards this will be work

```
var graphButton = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
   var button = `<button onclick="customMethod('${cell.getRow().getData()}')">myLabel</button>`;
   return button;
};
```